# Double integration problem in Apostol's Book.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve the following integral:
$$\displaystyle \int_{1}^8\int_{\sqrt[3]{y}}^y e^x \left(\dfrac{x}{y} \right) ^{1/2}dxdy.$$

I tried it for a few hours but I was unsuccesfully. Then I tried to solve it by some software but can't solve it in terms of elementary functions.

Another "face" of the integral changing the order of integration is this:
$$\displaystyle \int_{1}^2\int_{x}^{x^3} e^x \left(\dfrac{x}{y} \right) ^{1/2}dydx+\int_{2}^8\int_{x}^8 e^x \left(\dfrac{x}{y} \right) ^{1/2}dydx. \hspace{1cm} (1)$$

I worked with $(1).$ The first term of the sum is actually a known integral.
Second term still having trouble about elementary functions.

According to Apostol (Section 11.15, exercise 21, Vol. 2) the answer is $4e^8+\frac{2}{3}e$.

Can someone help me to solve it?

Comment: What happens when you reverse the order of integration?

Comment: Yeah, I tried by changing the order of integration but it doesn't works

Answer (score 2):

The answer you claim is from the text is much too large compared to the numeric result, so either you have written down the problem incorrectly, or the answer is incorrect.

To see why, note that $$f(x,y) = e^x \sqrt{x/y}$$ is bounded above by $$g(x,y) = 2 \sqrt{2} e^x$$ in the region of integration $$R = (1 \le y \le 8) \cap (y^{1/3} \le x \le y);$$ this much is clear by noting that $\sqrt{x/y}$ attains a global maximum on $[1,8] \times [1,8]$ when $x = 8$, $y = 1$, thus for the proper subset $R$, $g(x,y) \ge f(x,y) \ge 0$.  But $$\iint_R g(x,y) \, dA = 2 \sqrt{2} e \left(2-6 e+e^7\right) < 4e^8 + \frac{2}{3}e.$$

In fact, the bound can be made much tighter; the actual value is approximately $2721.68$ but this is sufficient to demonstrate that the provided answer is inconsistent with the problem as stated.